# Assertion failed - load matrix

Tags: c, file, matrix, fwrite

```
typedef struct {
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    size_t stride;
    float *es;
} Mat;
```

```
Mat t = mat_alloc(img_width*img_height, 3);
Mat mat_alloc(size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    Mat m;
    m.rows = rows;
    m.cols = cols;
    m.stride = cols;
    m.es = NN_MALLOC(sizeof(*m.es)*rows*cols);
    NN_ASSERT(m.es != NULL);
    return m;
}
```

NN_ASSERT - assert
NN_MALLOC - malloc

```
const char *out_file_path = "img.txt";
FILE *out = fopen(out_file_path, "w");

mat_save(out, t);

void mat_save(FILE *out, Mat m)
{
    const char *magic = "nn.h.mat";
    fwrite(magic, strlen(magic), 1, out);
    fwrite(&m.rows, sizeof(m.rows), 1, out);
    fwrite(&m.cols, sizeof(m.cols), 1, out);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m.rows; ++i) {
        size_t n = fwrite(&MAT_AT(m, i, 0), sizeof(*m.es), m.cols, out);
        while (n < m.cols && !ferror(out)) {
            size_t k = fwrite(m.es + n, sizeof(*m.es), m.cols - n, out);
            n += k;
        }
    }
}

#define MAT_AT(m, i, j) (m).es[(i)*(m).stride + (j)]
```

> Just so you know, the code is provided in a scattered manner and is not actually like that! :-)

Changed: Well, so as not to confuse myself and you, I will describe the problem in full

When I save a file using mat_save I get unreadable data and I realized that this is normal, but when I want to load my saved matrix I get an error from the mat_load function:

> Assertion failed: magic == 0x74616d2e682e6e6e, file ../Headers/nn.h, line 159

```
Mat mat_load(FILE *in)
{
    uint64_t magic;
    fread(&magic, sizeof(magic), 1, in);
    NN_ASSERT(magic == 0x74616d2e682e6e6e);
    size_t rows, cols;
    fread(&rows, sizeof(rows), 1, in);
    fread(&cols, sizeof(cols), 1, in);
    Mat m = mat_alloc(rows, cols);

    size_t n = fread(m.es, sizeof(*m.es), rows*cols, in);
    while (n < rows*cols && !ferror(in)) {
        size_t k = fread(m.es, sizeof(*m.es) + n, rows*cols - n, in);
        n += k;
    }

    return m;
}
```

Comment: (a) Edit the question to provide a [mre]. (b) If you expect to see human-readable data in the file, do not use `fwrite`. `fwrite` is for writing binary data. To write human-readable data, use `fprintf`.

Comment: And by the way, this is what I get from the mat_save function: https://i.ibb.co/qyzbwVB/file.png

Comment: What do you mean garbage in the file? If you expect to be able to read the file's content after writing with fwrite() then that's wrong. You are writing binary data, that is not going to be human readable.

Comment: I realized my mistake with fwrite, thanks friends! I just recently started learning C

Comment: I apparently just realized that the problem is not in the mat_save function at all, but rather in mat_load and that the data, apparently, should still be written using fwrite. Sorry. But I still don't understand how to fix it

Comment: Having two wildly different representations for the magic number is silly and dangerous.  Choose either the byte array or the 64-bit integer, but don't use both.  And print the magic number you did read so can start working out what went wrong.